# How to get two stereo camera images at the same time?

Tags: gstreamer

Dears

I would like to use the following stereo cameras with gstreamer.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07C2NTMRC/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07C2NTMRC)

・Item Name : SVPRO 720p HD Webcam

・USB port type : USB 2.0

・Resolution　：　1080x720

I set up two shells at the same time to get two images from the stereo camera simultaneously.

And I tried to acquire the camera image of each right and left at the same time with the following code respectively.

```html
###Stereo_Camera_Left###

#!/bin/bash
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
v4l2src device="/dev/video0" \
! decodebin \
! videoscale \
! videorate \
! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=80,height=60,framerate=\(fraction\)2/1" \
! videoconvert \
! autovideosink


###Stereo_Camera_Right###

#!/bin/bash
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
v4l2src device="/dev/video1" \
! decodebin \
! videoscale \
! videorate \
! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=80,height=60,framerate=\(fraction\)2/1" \
! videoconvert \
! autovideosink
```

However, the following error is displayed on either the left or right camera.
Only one image can be acquired.

```html
libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device
0:00:05.092236993  6216      0x1202940 ERROR         v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:635:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_streamon:<v4l2src0:pool:src> error with STREAMON 28 (No space left on device)
0:00:05.092283101  6216      0x1202940 WARN          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:1054:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_poll:<v4l2src0> error: poll error 1: No space left on device. (28)
0:00:05.092331654  6216      0x1202940 WARN                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:884:gst_v4l2src_create:<v4l2src0> error: Failed to allocate a buffer
0:00:05.092354187  6216      0x1202940 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2948:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: Internal data flow error
0:00:05.092362693  6216      0x1202940 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2948:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Could not read from resource
Additional debug info:
gstv4l2bufferpool.c(1054): gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_poll (): /GstPipeline:pipeline
```

Is there a way to get two images of this stereo camera at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways possible here:

1) BASH logic. Run the first command in the background via `&` at the end and start the second.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! decodebin ! videoscale ! videorate ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=80,height=60,framerate=\(fraction\)2/1" ! videoconvert ! autovideosink &
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device="/dev/video1" ! decodebin ! videoscale ! videorate ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=80,height=60,framerate=\(fraction\)2/1" ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

2) Recommended and "more correct" approach - put all the logic into one pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! decodebin ! videoscale ! videorate ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=80,height=60,framerate=\(fraction\)2/1" ! videoconvert ! autovideosink v4l2src device="/dev/video1" ! decodebin ! videoscale ! videorate ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=80,height=60,framerate=\(fraction\)2/1" ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I saved the two shells from the code I taught. However, one camera can not be displayed.
I think that '<v4l2src0> error: poll error 1: No space left on device.' Is probably suspicious.
Is there a way to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with a similar stereo camera - No space left on device.  I was trying to capture video at 640x480.  Lowering the capture width and height (to 320x240) for both camera solved the issue and I was able to get simultaneous video from the stereo camera.

I believe the error may be a limitation on the USB bandwidth from the device.